# ODE of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let assume I have the following ODE of second order

$$y''-y'=(y+1)^2 - y^2$$

Normally, using roots of the characteristic polynomial of this equation, I'd say the solutions are $e^{\lambda_1 t}$, $e^{\lambda_2 t}$ (assuming $\lambda_2\neq\lambda_1$). I also know how to find solutions of $ay''+by'+cy = f(t)$ (using Wronski matrix in that case). But should I do in this exercise? When I try to use the latter method, the result I obtain is some constant...

My attempt was to calculate $u_1(t)$,$u_2(t)$, where $y=u_1(t)e^{\lambda_1 t} + u_2(t)e^{\lambda_2 t}$ and $u_1'e^{\lambda_1 t} + u_2'e^{\lambda_2 t} = 0\\ \lambda_1 u_1'e^{\lambda_1 t} + \lambda_2 u_2'e^{\lambda_2 t} = 1$

Comment: Hint: simplify the RHS before you do anything else.

Comment: I get $y''+y'-2y=1$ and that is what I can't calcualte.

Comment: It should work using the Wronskian, or the homogenous solution/particular solution method, if you have learnt that.  If you post your complete working I'm sure someone can tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Jules: Undetermined Coefficients for the homogeneous part $y''-y'-2y = 0$ (you have a sign error), $(m^2-m-2 = 0 \rightarrow m_1 = -1, m_2 = 2)$, and $y_p = c$ for the particular part. Clear? You can also use the Laplace Transform, Variation of Parameters and maybe other approaches too.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think about that. Clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

characteristic polynomial of this equation is $r^2-r-2=0$ so that $r_1=2 , r_2=-1$ from here we have that $$y_h=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-x}$$ and  let $y_p=A$ therefore $-2A=1 $ and so we vahe $$y_p=-\frac{1}{2}$$